# How to load and analyze page in background without loading images/scripts?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

What's the best way to get usable DOM for an AJAX-requested page without loading any related images/scripts/etc?

<sub>**Backstory:**
I want to load a page in background, then perform a sort of data-mining on it (this is a browser extension, so I can't control the pages themselves). I do not want to spend time loading images and running scripts on the background page, since it is only page contents I need.</sub>

Comment: If you request the URL with AJAX, it shouldn't load the resources unless you add it to the DOM.

Comment: True, but how would I analyze the page contents if I do not add to the DOM?

Comment: It depends on how exactly you are analyzing the page, but, there is no reason you would need to add it to the DOM.  For instance, if you were using jQuery, you can use all of the same selectors as you could if the request was in the DOM.  Are you able to use jQuery?  Which browser are you building this for?  Can you tell me more about what you want to analyze?

Comment: I can use jQuery, what I want is to extract `<a>` based on certain criteria, also `<title>` contents, and some `<img>` srcs. If I use `$(html)`, will it create some kind of a document fragment without loading resources? Looking at documentation (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2), I see "... some browsers filter out certain elements such as <html>, <title>, or <head> elements. As a result, the elements inserted may not be representative of the original string passed" which might be a problem.

Comment: I would try it and see if it works.  You can grab <a> tags href attribute like this: `$("a", $(ajax_response)).attr("href");`  Title's contents: `$("title", $(ajax_response)).html();`  If you are writing a browser extension, you only have to worry about it working in one browser, right?  So, just try it and see if it works in your target browser.

Comment: Well, I tried it and it kind of works but it does lose the `<title>` (document fragment created is rather weird). Now the title is least important to me so for I now I will use `RegExp` for it and ignore possible issues. Can you turn your comment into an answer? This soultion is imperfect, but if there is no other way, it will do.

Answer (score 0):

1. load data via ajax
2. strip all the tags containing `src` and `href` attributes, or simply change the value of those attributes with `data:null`. If data also contains inline style you should remove all statements containing a reference to external resources (e.g. background and border images, `.htc` components, xul bindings, .ico cursor)
3. append filtered data to the DOM and analyze it

step 2 could be achieved through a regular expression in javascript.  e.g.

```
/* here we are in the ajax "success" callback */
...
data = data.replace(/(src|href|style)=['"]([^'"]+?)['"]/gi, 
function(match, attribute) {
   return (attribute.toLowerCase() === 'style')
       ? attribute + '=""'             /* remove all inline style */
       : attribute + '="data:null"';   /* href and src set to data:null */

})

/* append filtered data */
$(data).appendTo($('body_or_other_element'))
```

Comment: 1. Blacklist filtering is not a fail-safe method. 2. You do not need the DOM.

Comment: 1. it's not 100% safe but should cover common cases. 2. Could you clarify?

Comment: 1. No, that's the definition of "not fail-safe" -- don't do it because "common cases" are _not enough_. It's the cases you don't expect that are the problem. 2. Read comments from others.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of this solution, but I prefer not to use `RegExp` on html, it may create other problems. For example, you are removing some of `href` and `src` that I want to get. I could grab them from `RegExp`, but it does not provide the filtering I need, so I would have to preserve them as some other attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, use jQuery, as I mentioned above.  It makes it easy to select portions of the page DOM as needed.

Here are some examples:

You can grab  tags href attribute like this: $("a", $(ajax_response)).attr("href");

Title's contents: $("title", $(ajax_response)).html();

You might have to test out the selectors to see which work best, but, I think this would be an easy way of going about this.